# Tracking desktop app with Google Analytics

Tags: analytics

I want to track a c++ desktop app. I created an account on Google Analytics but I saw only 2 choices : track a web site or a mobile application. I choose mobile application and I received an ID like UA-xxxxxxxx-x . Now, I want to know if it's possible to track a desktop application with that ID, and how. I saw several examples on forums but each time a website is specified, but in my case I don't have any website, I just want to have statistics about my application (what are the features used etc...).

After that, I tried this example I found in Qt (of course there are not the final values)

```
void Analytics::initialize()
{
    m_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    // Call slot_receive() when reply is received
    QObject::connect(m_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),
                     this, SLOT(slot_receive(QNetworkReply *)));

    // Send requests to Google Analytics while app is running
    QTimer * timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(slot_requestAnalyticsView()));
    timer->start(5 * 60 * 1000); // send requests every 5 minutes
    slot_requestAnalyticsView(); // send first request
} 


void Analytics::slot_requestAnalyticsView()
{
    // create request and set URL of receiver
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QUrl host("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect");
    request.setUrl(host);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
                      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // setup parameters of request
    QString requestParams;
    requestParams += "v=1"; // version of protocol
    requestParams += "&t=pageview"; // type of request
    requestParams += "&tid="; // Google Analytics account
    requestParams += ANALYTICS_ID;

    requestParams += "&cid=";
    requestParams += getMacAddress(); // unique user identifier
    requestParams += "&dp=foobar"; // name of page (or app name)
    requestParams += "&ul=" + QLocale::system().name(); // language

    // send request via post method

    QString qPost = request.url().toString() + QString( "?" ) + requestParams;
    qDebug() << "\nPOST = " << qPost << "\n";
    m_manager->post(request, requestParams.toStdString().c_str());
} 

void Analytics::slot_receive(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
     // Output information about reply
    qDebug()<<"RequestUrl:" << reply->request().url();
    qDebug()<<"Status:" << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    qDebug()<<"Error:"<< reply->error();
    QByteArray bytes=reply->readAll();
    qDebug()<<"Contents" << QString::fromUtf8(bytes.data(), bytes.size());
}
```

and I put that code on my app, but each time I execute it, "slot_receive" is never called and there is no change on my statistic page on Google Analytics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [c++ client](https://github.com/qmonix/client-cpp) for [Qmonix](http://qmonix.com) analytics.

For now the client only works on POSIX compliant operating systems and depends on libcurl for HTTP communication. But I believe it can be easily ported to support other platforms too.

Briefly, Qmonix is analytics SDK that provides server software to be installed on your own machine, no cloud services involved. It uses HTTP for communication.
Qmonix allows custom events, it's not Web or mobile specific (although there are JavaScript and Android libs).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
The only difference I see is I use "text/plain".

```
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "text/plain");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I evaluated the Measurement Protocol a while ago and remember having this question. You can select the mobile application and just use the ID for a desktop application.
I have built a wrapper (in .Net though) which I used in a test application to send some telemetry. To post events I used this string matrix:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> BuildEventPostString(TelemetryType type, string category, string action, string label,int? value = null)
{

    var result = new Dictionary<string, string> {

          { "v", "1" },
          { "tid", "UA-XXXXXXXX-2" },
          { "cid", "5ea42fb3-1af0-4f7b-XXXX-9a65f7bb84e8"},
          { "t", type.ToString() },
          { "ec", category },
          { "ea", action },
       };
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(label))
    {
        result.Add("el", label);
    }
    if (value.HasValue)
    {
        result.Add("ev", value.ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope it helps... The measurement protocol is a bit trickier to work with as it is basically plain HTTP so you need to build a wrapper around it and expose some APIs that you will use in your application.
The company I represent has SDKs especially designed for this use case, including C++.
Note: I am associated with Revulytics.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do exactly the same to track my free vs paid installations of my shareware software.
I ended up making my own library, which I am also giving to other developers who might want to benefit from it. 
Just a small DLL, no dependencies on .net or other libraries.
https://www.starmessagesoftware.com/softmeter/how-it-works-application-analytics

Answer (score -2):

Google Analytics is mainly for web and mobile apps, it may be not available for your desktop app. You can choose another analytics tool to make it such as DeskMetrics, DeskAppTrack, etc.

Comment: Google analytics works with both desktop, mobile and web applications. You can sending event using the measurement protocol directly.